# Magento image cache

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

Doing a daily backup of images folder `/media/catalog/product/`, is it safe and recommended NOT to backup `/media/catalog/product/cache/`?

The size is very large for backing up and when it to restore!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is safe, probably recommended you don't. Even if you did have to restore your catalog/product folder you would most likely need to flush the image cache anyway and then they would be regenerated.

Comment: Plus the darn thing will be full of images from discontinued product, Magento does no housecleaning when product is deleted, leaving both the original images and cached resized images until they are manually removed. For the original images, there's a module called "Image Clean", for the cached images, I just create a script that deletes cached images over 6 months old and let Magento recreate what's still in the catalog. The latter saves clicking the "clear image cache" button and having the site bog while recreating every cached image on page reload.